# Drools. NullPointerException if set field by FactType

Tags: drools

I declared the element to insert by .drl syntax:

```
declare TheElement
  myfield:long
end
```

and I try to set the field in my javacode:

```
FactType type = base.getFactType(PACKAGE, "TheElement");
Object myObj = type.newInstance();
type.set(myObj , "myfield", 226); //if I comment this line the insert is ok but the     field was not set
handle = session.insert(myObj);

session.fireAllRules();
```

I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.drools.factmodel.ClassDefinition.set(ClassDefinition.java:232)
at org.rec.Session.notify(Session.java:124)....
```

Comment: Works for me with 5.3.0, 5.4.0, 5.5.0

Comment: I "solved" the problem by setting the myField by a rule:
    rule "set timestamp"
      when
 $las:LeftArmStretched();
      then
 System.out.println("// timestamp changed!!");
 $las.setTime(clock.getCurrentTime());
      end